# Safari address bar at the bottom creating unwanted spacing

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive

I'd like to move the white div parallel to the address bar at the bottom (once the bar goes up/down), or just put it permanently at the bottom of the page, below the address bar. Safari positions div with `bottom: 0px;` above the address bar and once it goes down, it stays there, creating an unwanted gap. How do I cope with this?

[Address bar up (ok)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrGyT.png)

[Address bar down (creating unwanted gap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8rtJ.png)

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] in your question